# SDK for Avatars (such as Wii, XBOX 360 avatars)

Tags: directx, 3d, direct3d

What are some software packages available to provide 90% of the avatar functionality for my games? My favorite is xbox's Avatar system (but I want it in my PC games).

I need the ability to customize the looks of a person (body, clothes, etc...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks lile [miieditor.com](http://miieditor.com/) was shut by Nintendo ..

there's some info [here](http://aj.heypoorplayer.org/mii/) on Mii editors .. some source code is available .. not much to get excited about tho ..

and then there is the open-source [MakeHuman](http://www.makehuman.org/blog/index.php) project .. which is totally the other side of the spectrum :)

Answer (score 1):

The November XDK (Xbox Developer Kit) contains an avatar API, but it's use is restricted from what I understand. The game using it must carry an E rating. Getting access to the XDK isn't an easy OR a cheap direction.

Your other option is to develop on the XNA platform, but the avatar functionality isn't available yet. It's already been submitted as a suggestion, but at this time, there isn't any information on as to if or when it will be available.

[XNA Avatar Suggestion](https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=356893&SiteID=226)

EDIT: Just re-read your post and realized that you're looking for an alternative. I'm not aware of any pre-built packages and will most likely require you to roll-your-own.

Comment: You need to go to this url twice to get it to work, even after you login.  http://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=356893&SiteID=226

Answer (score 0):

They're all custom systems so I doubt a single SDK for that very purpose exists. Sure if you want to make a game which uses XBox' avatars there's an SDK/API for that provided by Microsoft but as far as I know, none exist as a ready-to-use package.

Comment: I don't expect to get the Microsoft version, but surely there has to be a product out there that I can integrate in my game...